# Asynchronous Queries in node.js, waiting and promises

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a hard time being able to chain functions in node.js, i can't get the receiver to wait.
Shouldn't promises be asynchronous and therefore suited for such a task?

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var input = 'SELECT * FROM ideas;';
  connection.query(input, (err, results) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject();
    } else {
      console.log('success');
      results = JSON.stringify(results);
      console.log(results);
      resolve();
      return results;
    }
  })
});

promise.then(function(results) {
  results = JSON.parse(results);
  console.log(results);
});
```

I hope someone knows what I am missing here and can help!

Comment: FYI, if you install and use [`require('mysql2/promise');`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper), then you can use built-in promise support with your database rather than manually promisifying each operation.

Answer (score 1):

> You only need to add `results` to `resolve` and `err` to `reject`.

For an example, you can use this code below:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var input = 'SELECT * FROM ideas;';
  connection.query(input, (err, results) => {
    if(err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success');
      results = JSON.stringify(results);
      console.log(results);
      resolve(results);
    }
  })
});

promise.then(function(results) {
  results = JSON.parse(results);
  console.log(results);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Send some data back in the reject() or the resolve() statement, Currently you are expecting some results but noting is being sent back. Just convert your Reject and Resolve statement like this:
`resolve(results);`
`reject(err);`

An Extra tip, also chain a catch block with the promise.then call so that exceptions are also handled successfully. as following
`promise.then(function() {`
`//code if promise resolves`
`}).catch(function(){`
`//code if promise rejects`
`});`